# I just arrived to New York city

Tags: prepositions

> I just **arrived to** New York city with a bag full of tank tops and shorts ... [Amanda Cerny](https://twitter.com/AmandaCerny/status/578764272756482048)

Can we use *to* with *arrive* verb? or we should use *at*?

> I just arrived **at** New York city ...

Comment: **in** I just arrived in NYC. I arrived **at** the terminal **in** NYC.

Comment: Agreed with @WillowRex.  I don't know who this Amanda Cerny is, but that is definitely not standard usage.  You arrive **in** large places like countries or cities, and **at** smaller places like buildings.  You never arrive **to** a place.

Comment: Thank you guys, @stangdon Amanda Cerny is an American actress

Comment: She's looks like a FOREIGN MODEL. So, she missed the in. Arrive in NYC, get to NYC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NYC is a large place which you probably are *inside of*

> I just *arrived* **in** NYC

It is possible to say

> I just *arrived* **at** the house

which means you are in the vicinity of the house or next to it, but is often used in relation to a landmark

> I just arrived **at** NYC

is possible but may sound awkward to native ears, it might be understood as "I just arrived at the airport in NYC"

Usually **to** is used with

> I just *came* **to** NYC
>   I just *got* **to** NYC