# "I came to Paris." or "I got to Paris."

Tags: word-choice, verbs

> I came to Paris.
>   I got to Paris.

Have any difference of the above sentence?

Comment: Related question:  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/120672

Answer (score 3):

Yes,

**I came to Paris** means that you **brought yourself** to Paris, either by bus, plane, or whatever.

**I got to Paris** means that you **arrived** in Paris. You were on your way to Paris and you **arrived** in your final destination which was Paris.

Comment: Why does Paris have to be the final destination?

Comment: Good thinking. It doesn't.

Comment: Should "arrived to" be changed to "arrived at" or "arrived in"?

Comment: My bad everyone. I'm a non-native speaker, and sometimes I can't spot mistakes like that. I need to get better at English myself.

Comment: I just read an article about which preposition should be used after "arrived", and in the article it's mentioned that for big places such as countries, cities and etc... use "in", now for a small place such as restaurant or a movie theater you should use "at".